# Can't do fopen when using NSTask to run an executable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, fopen, nstask

### What I want to do

To run an executable "server" from my Cocoa app. The executable can already run perfectly when invoked in the terminal and will read a text file in the same directory.

### What I've done

Put "server" and other files in the "Supporting Files" folder in Xcode. Use NSTask to run "server":

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"server" ofType:nil];
NSArray *args = [[NSArray alloc] init];
[NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:path arguments:args];
```

### The error

The executable couldn't open a text file. Specifically, a C function `fopen("tradingbook_closing.txt", "r")` in the source code failed to open the file. But the file was there and running the executable in the terminal directly goes flawless. And the app is not sandboxed. Could anyone find what went wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a *relative* path for the file, `"tradingbook_closing.txt"`, which relies on the current directory for the process to be the one containing that file. This is probably the cause of your error.

It is best not to hardwire relative paths into a program, but if you must you can set the current directory of the process launched by `NSTask` using the `currentDirectoryPath` property. You'll need to create an `NSTask` instance, rather than using the class method `launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:arguments:` and then set the `launchPath`, `arguments` and `currentDirectoryPath` properties before calling the `launch` method.

Comment: Incredible advice. `[task setCurrentDirectoryPath:dirPath]` fix the whole thing. Big thanks to you!